# Sequence of integrable functions on $[0,1]$ with a certain bound on the $L_1$-norm converges to 0 a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given a sequence of integrable functions $f_n$ on $[0,1]$ that satisfy $\int_0^1 |f_n| dx \le 1/n^2$, I'm trying to show $f_n \to 0$ a.e.

I was considering the set $A \subset [0,1]$ which consists of the $x$ values for which $f_n$ does not converge to 0 and trying to show it had measure 0. In order to incorporate the hypothesis, I thought maybe doing
$$
\int_A dx \le \int_A \frac{|f_n(x)|}{\epsilon} dx \le \frac{1}{n^2\epsilon},
$$ 
where the $\epsilon$ arises from the fact that $f_n(x) \not \to 0$ for $x\in A$. However, this doesn't quite sit right because the second part of the question says to show it isn't true if we replace $1/n^2$ with $1/\sqrt{n}$, in which case the above accomplishes the same thing. My intuition says it has something to do with the fact that $\sum 1/n^2$ converges while $\sum 1/\sqrt{n}$ does not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another idea:

Put $g=\sum |f_n|$. We see that (as all the functions are $\geq 0$) we have $$\int_0^1g(t)dt=\sum _{n\geq 1}\int_0^1|f_n(t)|dt\leq \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2}<+\infty$$

Hence $g$ is in $L^1$, hence finite $a.e$, and the serie $|f_n|$ is a.e convergent, and $f_n\to 0$ a.e.

Comment: Really nice; lovely proof!

Answer (score 1):

If $B_n = \{x: |f_n(x)| > 1/\sqrt{n}\}$, we have 
$$m(B_n) \le\sqrt{n} \int |f_n|\; dx \le n^{-3/2}$$
so that 
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty m(B_n) < \infty $$
For any $M$, 
$$m \{x: |f_n(x)| \ge 1/\sqrt{n} \ \text{infinitely often}\} \le m(\bigcup_{n\ge M} B_n) $$
which goes to $0$ as $M \to \infty$.  Thus for almost all $x$, $|f_n(x)| < 1/\sqrt{n}$ for all but finitely many $n$, and in particular $f_n(x) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.